# How to use Selenium to interact with this pop-up login

Tags: selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to log into a website and download financial reports. Here is the link:

https://reports.mobilizecollections.com/home/browse/

I know what I would need to do if the login info had an attached ID, but I have not encountered a pop-up login form like this before. How can I interact with that using Selenium? Is it even possible?

[Inspect element and website picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr5at.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the URL like this :

```
username = "some username"
password = "some password"
URL = "https://" +username +":" +password +"@"+ "reports.mobilizecollections.com/home/browse/"
```

and in Python I would do this :

```
driver.get(URL)
```